# requests.get is very slow while fetching websites

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to build a simple terminal app to search stuff online through the terminal.
When I submit get requests through the library, I get very large wall times. I can't seem to pinpoint the problem.

Its fast when I directly type into the browser.

I have already skipped proxies in my script file (not shown here). The question has already been closed on requests as it is not a bug in requests according to peers.

```
In [ 1 ]: import requests    
In [ 2 ]: %%time
     ...: response = requests.get('http://en.wikipedia.org')    
     ...:    
CPU times: user 123 ms, sys: 11.9 ms, total: 135 ms     
Wall time: 4min 22s
```

Comment: please insert text, no images

Comment: Hmm I run it and get `CPU times: user 59.5 ms, sys: 497 µs, total: 60 ms
Wall time: 1.88 s`. Is your internet connection slow on your end?

Comment: Hi @RoadRunner. Your solution seems to be the right one. Tried on faster connections. It worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with internet connection speeds. When tried with faster internet connections, the script runs considerably faster while the browser search seems to perform approximately the same way.

> in short: better to use faster internet connections with requests than
>   with browsers